# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Popen' error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using Python 2.7 and Google appengine to create an application.  I get the following error when I try to run the application using the devappserver.py.

```
 from google.appengine.api import mail_stub
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\mail_stub.py", line 50, in <module>
    class MailServiceStub(apiproxy_stub.APIProxyStub):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\mail_stub.py", line 223, in MailServiceStub
    popen=subprocess.Popen,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Popen'
2015-04-16 16:35:43 (Process exited with code 1)
```

This problem didn't occur until I changed the PYTHONPATH to `google\google_appengine\lib\webob-1.1.1;`

How can I fix this?

Comment: You shouldn't have to set the PYTHONPATH; why are you doing that?

Comment: because I used to get error messages regarding the webob lib.

Comment: There's no reason you should need to set your PYTHONPATH to that (dev_appserver will take care of that for you). Please revert that setting and figure out why you need that.

Comment: I fixed the problem by re-installing the Python again....Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

System calls are not allowed by Google App Engine sandbox - that includes Popen().
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Python_The_sandbox

Answer (score 1):

The solution found by the original poster was to re-install his Python interpreter and doing so, solve any misconfiguration error.